# Scala, @ResponseBody, and Map

Tags: spring, scala, spring-mvc

I'm experimenting with Scala in a spring3 project, and I'm not getting what I expect when I return a map with @ResponseBody. I'm including a working example in java along with my attempt in scala

```
// This is Java
@RequestMapping(value="/pbx.admin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getInfo2(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("pbx", "admin");
    map.put("method", "s");
    return map;
}
```

The java returns json with the pbx & method defined, which is what I'm expecting.

```
// This is Scala
@RequestMapping(value= Array("/pbx.admin"), 
  method=Array(RequestMethod.GET))
@ResponseBody
def getInfo2() = {
  Map("pbx" -> "admin", "method" -> "s")
}
```

The scala returns something different though:

```
{
    empty: false,
    traversableAgain: true
}
```

What do I need to do in order to get my map keys / values?

And for extra credit, Is there a better 'scala way' to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring MVC framework wasn't built with Scala in mind and it doesn't recognize Scala's `Map`. You must convert `scala.collection.Map` to `java.util.Map`. You can either use implicit conversion:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._

def getInfo2(): java.util.Map[String, String] = {
  Map("pbx" -> "admin", "method" -> "s")
}
```

or convert it manually:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

def getInfo2() = {
  Map("pbx" -> "admin", "method" -> "s").asJava
}
```

Mind the imports, they are important.

I suspect Spring can be hacked to accept Scala collections, but obviously not out-of-the box.

Comment: So, when Spring MVC didn't recognize the scala.collection.Map as a Map, it decided to apply the strategy it uses to serialize JavaBeans, namely finding all of the methods that meet JavaBean conventions, and using those as the elements of the JSON object. There are two methods that meet these criteria: `isEmpty` and `isTraversableAgain`.

Comment: @KenBloom: exactly, +1 for great comment. Similar things happen when you try to return Scala's `List`.

Comment: @KenBloom Neat, What I was expecting to happen was for my map to be converted into a java.util.HashMap at compilation, but that is me being a scala newbie :)

Answer (score 7):

Spring MVC uses Jackson. You need to register the Jackson scala module as a mapper. This adds support for scala to Jackson allowing it to recognize the collections.

Example:

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaModule
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule  
    class ScalaObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper  {
        {
            registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        }
    }
```

Then you need to add it to you message converters

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
            <mvc:message-converters>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.petzfactor.packwall.web.module.ScalaObjectMapper"></bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

The module is on github at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

Answer (score 0):

Scala module is required to serialize scala objects such as Collections, Option and case classes. Here is a way to register the Jackson Scala module only by modifying the Spring context.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapperWithScala"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean name="scalaModule" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule"/>
<bean name="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>
<bean name="objectMapperWithScala" factory-bean="objectMapper" factory-method="registerModule">
    <constructor-arg ref="scalaModule"/>
</bean>
```